# Get unique elements for an array of objects matching two elements only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects, for example:

```
[#<Something id: 34175, name: "abc", value: 123.3, comment: "something here">,
 #<Something id: 34176, name: "xyz", value: 123.3, comment: "something here">,
 #<Something id: 34177, name: "xyz", value: 227.3, comment: "something here sdfg">,
 #<Something id: 34178, name: "xyz", value: 123.3, comment: "something here sdfg">]
```

I want to return all elements that do not have the same name and value. So in this case the return would be:

```
[#<Something id: 34175, name: "abc", value: 123.3, comment: "something here">,
 #<Something id: 34176, name: "xyz", value: 123.3, comment: "something here">,
 #<Something id: 34177, name: "xyz", value: 227.3, comment: "something here sdfg">]
```

All I care about is the name and value.

I tried passing a block to the `uniq` method, but I can't figure out how to match by two elements and not just one.

Comment: This should do it: `a.uniq { |instance| [instance.name, instance.value] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland post as an answer

Comment: @CarySwoveland that did it! Thanks for your help. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the form of [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) that takes a block.

**Code**

```
arr.uniq { |instance| [instance.name, instance.value] }
```

**Example**

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :value, :comment
  def initialize(id, name, value, comment)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @value = value
    @comment = comment
  end
end

arr = [Something.new(34175, "abc", 123.3, "something here"),
       Something.new(34176, "xyz", 123.3, "something here"),
       Something.new(34177, "xyz", 227.3, "something here sdfg"),
       Something.new(34178, "xyz", 123.3, "something here sdfg")]
  #=> [#<Something:0x000001012cc2f0 @id=34175, @name="abc", @value=123.3,
  #      @comment="something here">,
  #    #<Something:0x000001012cc278 @id=34176, @name="xyz", @value=123.3,
  #      @comment="something here">,
  #    #<Something:0x000001012cc200 @id=34177, @name="xyz", @value=227.3,
  #      @comment="something here sdfg">,
  #    #<Something:0x000001012cc0e8 @id=34178, @name="xyz", @value=123.3,
  #      @comment="something here sdfg">]

arr.uniq { |instance| [instance.name, instance.value] }

  #=> [#<Something:0x000001012cc2f0 @id=34175, @name="abc", @value=123.3,
  #      @comment="something here">,
  #    #<Something:0x000001012cc278 @id=34176, @name="xyz", @value=123.3,
  #      @comment="something here">,
  #    #<Something:0x000001012cc200 @id=34177, @name="xyz", @value=227.3,
  #      @comment="something here sdfg">]
```